# how to use marionette CollectionView to fetch data deom the server?

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I am trying to create a simple Marionette(2.3.2) Application, that retrieves data from a RESTFUL web service, 
What did I do wrong? how to fix this code? and what is the best structure for this sample App?

here the code on jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/kdureidy/zaze13fw/

here is my code:

```
var Library = new Backbone.Marionette.Application();

var LayoutView = Backbone.Marionette.LayoutView.extend({
    el: 'body',
    template: '#content-template',

    regions: {
        mainRegion: "#main-region",
        collectionRegion: "#collection-region"
    }
});

var Book = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: "http://localhost:9090/library-0.1/books"
});

var MyChildView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    model: Book,
    tagName: 'li',
    template: '#list-template',
});

var BooksCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: 'http://localhost:9090/library-0.1/books',
    model: Book
});

var collection1 = new BooksCollection({
    model: Book
});

var MyCollectionView = Backbone.Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
    url: "http://localhost:9090/library-0.1/books",
    tagName: 'ul',
    childView: MyChildView,
    collectionEvents: {
        'sync': 'render'
    },
});

var c = new MyCollectionView({
    collection: collection1
});

Library.layout_view = new LayoutView();
Library.layout_view.render();
Library.layout_view.collectionRegion.show(c);

Library.start();
```

my templates are:

```
<script id="list-template" type="text/template">
        <h2><%=title %></h2>
        <span><%=author %></span>

        <button>Click Here</button>
    </script>

    <script id="content-template" type="text/template">
        <h1>This is Lesson 1</h1>
        <div id="main-region" class="content">
        </div>

        <hr>

        <div id="collection-region"></div>
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `CollectionView` does not fetch data, it renders it, Backbone.Collection is the one responsible for fetching the data.
2. You don't need url in `MyCollectionView`
3. Marionette has `collectionEvents`, which you can use the same way as `modelEvents`, so your initialize can be replaced with

   ```
   collectionEvents: {
       'reset': 'render'
       'change': 'render'
   }
   ```

   and call, which I would do separately

   ```
   `collection1.fetch()` explicitly
   ```
4. For good Marionette app structure look at: http://www.backbonerails.com/

Comment: Ok, That's fixed an issues, now I see the collection with the fetched data, but I noticed that it access the render()  function twice, first time before the fetch, and it shows the collection with the default model data, and the second time it shows all the fetched data! how can I make it render once?

Comment: I want it to render only after fetch

Comment: It's because of how you defined collection events. You can limit collectionEvents to { "sync" : "render" }, and it will be re rendered only on fetch.

Comment: I put the code on http://jsfiddle.net/kdureidy/zaze13fw/
can you take a look there and help me fix it?